# How to ensure wasm memory is freed when using it from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I have a C library that looks like this:

```
struct timeseries *ts_create(void) {
    /* Allocate some memory and return a pointer. */
}

void ts_free(struct timeseries *p) {
    /* Free the memory block pointed to by p. */
}

/* And many other functions that receive a struct timeseries * and
 * do things to it.
 */
```

I've compiled this with `emscripten` and I'm creating a JavaScript interface (wrapper) to it, like this:

```
const timeseries = {
  ptimeseries: 0,

  initialize() {
    this.ptimeseries = cfunctions.ts_create();
  },

  destroy() {
    cfunctions.ts_free(this.ptimeseries);
  },

  // And many other functions
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
const myTimeseries = Object.create(timeseries);
try {
  myTimeseries.initialize();
  // do more things
} finally {
  myTimeseries.destroy();
}
```

The problem is that I'd like to keep the "dangerous" stuff, i.e. the memory allocation and freeing, in C (or in the JavaScript wrapper), so that the JavaScript programmer can use the resulting library safely. JavaScript programmers are used to objects freeing themselves automatically, and requiring them to add some kind of `try ... finally` statement is error prone.

But as far as I can see JavaScript doesn't have any object destructors or any kind of `onGarbageCollect(object)` event.

What can I do about this?

Comment: I'm not intricately familiar with WASM, so this is a comment rather than an answer. Javascript handles garbage collecting automatically: when there are no more references to an object, it can be freed. Given WASM's sandbox model, I would be very surprised if this didn't extend to things allocated there. So in the above example, I would expect the memory to be freed when `myTimeseries` has no more lingering references. You should be able to test by creating an instance, then assigning it to `undefined` (or just reaching end of the script) and then checking the memory state in the debugger.

Comment: @Etheryte If WASM decides to allocate something automatically, it's likely to free it automatically, as you said (although I'm not aware of anything like this actually happening). But here we have a case where I allocated something manually (i.e. by running `malloc()`). I don't believe WASM will free that; in fact I think it can't, because it doesn't know what references exist for it.

Comment: While I see where you're coming from, this doesn't match up with my understanding of how WASM works. Feel free to correct me if I'm mistaken somewhere, as far as I know compiled WASM is run [in a sandbox](https://webassembly.org/docs/security/), the `malloc()` call above isn't equivalent to having a C `malloc()` call, even if it may be the source language. Once your WASM module gets garbage collected, so too should thus the memory. The dynamic memory allocation only looks that way, internally it's implemented differently.

Comment: @Etheryte Do you mean that when the WASM module is closed its memory will be freed? I agree. It won't free any malloced memory while it's active though. AFAIU it will be leaking until the user presses something like Ctrl+R on the browser (effectively restarting the application).

Comment: Yes, sorry if my explanation wasn't very clear earlier. As for the freeing, I would expect it to be freed as soon as the instance is garbage collected (as I explained above), as opposed to a page reload, but I'm not familiar with how WASM is implemented at that detail. If you already have a runnable example, you should be able to test this though by using the memory debugging tab in the browser developer tools. A simple test case would be to create an instance, check that it takes up memory, then clear the reference, and then check whether the memory is freed.

Comment: The size of a memory page in wasm is 64KB. I **think** that if you create a  WebAssembly Memory instance with `new WebAssembly.Memory({initial:10, maximum:100});` your C code can allocate up to the meaximum size (here 6.4MB) and memory will be freed automatically by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a new JavaScript feature known as FinalizationRegistry which you can use for this functionality, but note that it is not yet supported across all browsers (https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_finalizationregistry)

```js
const registry = new FinalizationRegistry((heldValue) => {
  cfunctions.ts_free(heldValue);
});

class Timeseries {
  constructor() {
    this.ptimeseries = cfunctions.ts_create();
    registry.register(this, this.ptimeseries, this);
  }

  destroy() { // manual destructor for backup, you don't have to call this
    registry.unregister(this);
    cfunctions.ts_free(this.ptimeseries);
  }
}
```